# Delete tags between specific tags in XML (Notepad++)

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

I already used the search function but I didn't find a answer to my question.

I have a XML structure like the following (example):

```
<Task name="1B">
 <Person type ="XX" name="YY" height="ZZ"/>
 <Person type ="XX" name="YY" height="ZZ"/> 
 <Person type ="XX" name="YY" height="ZZ"/> 
 </Task>

 <Task name="1C">
 <Person type ="XX" name="YY" height="ZZ"/>
 <Person type ="XX" name="YY" height="ZZ"/> 
 <Person type ="XX" name="YY" height="ZZ"/> 
 </Task>
```

Now I want to delete via Notepad++ the tag  with Name "1B" and all the tags between the open and closing tag. Is there a way in Notepad? I already tried with RegEx Pattern but I didn't get the right way.

Comment: Search `<Task name="1B">.*?<\/Task>` Replace with nothing.

Comment: Doesn't work. Can't find text in my XML.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex with HTML is strongly discouraged since that leads to many issues and unnecessary questions. See [**RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). **Using XSLT to transform XML is the tool you really need here.**

Create a UTF8 encoded file with a `remove_xml_tag.xsl` sample name and paste this into it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Task[@name='1B']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XSL processes each node and attribute (`node()|@*`) and when it encounters a `Task` element with `name` attribute equal to `1B` (`"Task[@name='1B']"`) it just does not write it into the output.

Then run the **XML Tools** plugin -> **XSL Transformation**. You will see:

[image]

Click the <kbd>...</kbd> button on the right and browse the XSL file.

Click the <kbd>Transform</kbd> button.

A fallback solution in case you have a malformed XML that will work only if you have no nested `Task` nodes:

```
<Task\s+name="1B">[^<]*(?:<(?!/Task>)[^<]*)*</Task>
```